# Get Instagram User ID Beyond Username

Tags: android, ios, instagram, instagram-api

I'd like to identify users beyond their username. Is there any way to identify users with a token/code/ID# that is static and will **never** change?

Simply because usernames are flexible and can be changed at any time meaning I cannot keep track users.

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dani you can track users by their user id, which stays static even if they change their username.

In Instagram's API example they use this endpoint: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`
which gives the following response:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
    "counts": {
        "media": 1320,
        "follows": 420,
        "followed_by": 3410
    }
```

}

Depending on what data or which endpoints you are hitting beforehand, you should be able to get to the user ID and use that accordingly throughout your application.